# How can I set the y axis of this `geom_tile` to have a formatted `yearmon` label at each point?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, zoo

I have a heat map showing a value with the year month pairing of the observation in the y axis, and the hour of the observation in the bottom axis. The data is held in a `data.table` object.

In default `ggplot2` the graph looks like this:

[image: base ggplot]

```
ggplot(repeatability, aes(x = iHrMi, y = iYrMo, fill = erraticity)) +
    geom_tile() +
    facet_grid(. ~ off) +
    scale_x_discrete(name = "Time", breaks = c("00:00", "12:00"))
```

Which is sort of fine, but my goal is to have the labels on the y axis include the abbreviated name, not the the number, of the month, and retain their order. `zoo` has extensions of `ggplot2` which allow you to chart `yearmon` objects like so:

[image: with zoo::yearmon and expand = 0]

```
ggplot(repeatability, aes(x = iHrMi, y = zoo::as.yearmon(iYrMo), fill = erraticity, group = iYrMo)) +
    geom_tile() +
    facet_grid(. ~ off) + 
    zoo::scale_y_yearmon(name = "Year Month", expand = c(0,0)) +
    scale_x_discrete(name = "Time", breaks = c("00:00", "12:00"))
```

This has the right format, but not the right number of labels, I want one for each month. Additionally, if `expand` is left to default, the y axis expands and includes periods that don't have data there.

If I supply an `n` argument though, to get 12 labels, this happens:

[image: with zoo::yearmon and expand = 0 AND n= 12]

I don't get twelve rows, but I get an extra odd label blow the x axis intercept.

```
ggplot(repeatability, aes(x = iHrMi, y = zoo::as.yearmon(iYrMo), fill = erraticity, group = iYrMo)) +
    geom_tile() +
    facet_grid(. ~ off) + 
    zoo::scale_y_yearmon(name = "Year Month", expand = c(0,0), n = 12) +
    scale_x_discrete(name = "Time", breaks = c("00:00", "12:00"))
```

This is the head of the table used to make it. I'm afraid I'm not sure how to dput the full table in a useful manner. I'll update this if anyone has any useful suggestions as to how to include a fuller version:

```
structure(list(iYrMo = c("2013-08", "2013-08", "2013-08", "2013-08", 
"2013-08", "2013-08"), iHrMi = c("00:00", "00:30", "01:00", "01:30", 
"02:00", "02:30"), off = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Weekday", 
"Weekend/Holiday"), class = "factor"), fit = c(0.883255368890743, 
0.888802101750935, 0.887399903327103, 0.896846543832244, 0.895936947283074, 
0.898059799540441), erraticity = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), .Label = c("Most", "More", "Less", "Least"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("iYrMo", 
"iHrMi", "off", "fit", "erraticity"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that yearmon is just a double type, with `0` equaling `Jan 0000` and `2013 + 6/12` equaling `July 2013`

You can use the limits and breaks arguments (same as in `scale_y_continuous` from ggplot):

```
library(zoo)
ggplot(repeatability, aes(x = iHrMi, y = as.yearmon(iYrMo), fill = erraticity, group = iYrMo)) +
  geom_tile() +
  facet_grid(. ~ off) + 
  scale_y_yearmon(name = "Year Month", limits = c(2013,2015), breaks = seq(2013,2015, by = 1/12)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Time", breaks = c("00:00", "12:00"))
```

Which with your reproducible data gives:

[image]

Messy, but the axis is correct.

Comment: Thanks, the axis is indeed correct, so that's half of it done. Still got the issue with the axis expanding outside the data range though. To modify this approach to both satisfy the correct axis limits and include the correct `expand` argument I will be using: `scale_y_yearmon(name = "Year Month", expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(repeatability[, min(as.yearmon(iYrMo))],repeatability[,max(as.yearmon(iYrMo))], by = 1/12)`. This also allows the scales limits to be reactive to the data set while ensuring there are always 12 labels. Thanks for the help.